# Unable to change value of input box to selected option of comboBox

Tags: javascript, html, function, printing

I'm following an introduction-course to HTML, in this particular demo I made a comboBox:

```
//Combobox to select a course
<div>
        <select id="courses" multiple size="3" onchange="choiceMade(this.value);">
            <option value="" selected>--Choose--</option>
            <option value="Angular">Angular</option>
            <option value="ReactJS">React</option>
            <option value="VueJS">Vue</option>
            <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
            <option value="Python">Python</option>
       </select>
</div>
```

The selected value should be printed in this `input` box using JavaScript:

```
//Inputbox where above selected course should be printed
<div>
     <label class="standoutLabel">Favorite Course:</label>
     <input type="text"  id="courseName">
</div>
```

The course tells me the `function` to do this should be this:

```
//Function to print selected choice in inputbox
function choiceMade(choice) {
    document.getElementByID("courseName").value = choice;
}
```

In the video it works fine, but for me... Nope...Nothing...Nada

How do I get this to work? What am I missing?

I tried adding a function call to get the value of `choiceMade` so it would input the `choice` in the `<input>`, but it just isn't working.

Comment: Typo: `getElementByID` should be `getElementById`. Easily found if you click [edit] and create a [mcve] using the `[<>]` snippet editor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small error in the JavaScript code.
The correct method to get an element by its ID is getElementById (with a lowercase “d”), not getElementByID (with an uppercase “D”). Below is the corrected choiceMade function:

```
// Function to print the selected choice in the input box
function choiceMade(choice) {
    document.getElementById("courseName").value = choice;
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I missed that...

Thanks for the help!